# Developing new version of iOS app. Need new bundle ID?

Tags: ios, version-control, version, bundle

I'm working on a new version of an app that is currently on the App Store.  I'd like to keep the current version on my testing device while developing the new version alongside it. That way, I can easily access the public version (e.g., during customer support) while developing the new version.

Does that mean I change the bundle ID from com.company.myapp to com.company.myappV1_1?

If so, should I change it back to com.company.myapp when uploading to the App Store?

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What you describe is your only option if you want both versions on your device during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a unique bundle ID on your device or else that'll overwrite the old version. When you submit to the AppStore you can change the bundle ID back to the initial one and overwrite. You basically answered your own question, since it's imperative bundle ID's are unique.